# Appending new positions to a form listbox

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a UserForm in Excel with a ListBox, which must show the result of a computation. The problem is when I try to fill the Listbox using a recursive loop the information which was there earlier is replaced with new data. How can I append new information to the content in the ListBox and not lose earlier information?

My current code:

```
Dim Form As HistoryFRM, ARR(), i,  ArrHistory()
.....
Set Form = New HistoryFRM
With Form
    .Show vbModeless
    .LBHistory.ColumnCount = 6
    For i = 0 To UBound(ARR)
        ArrHistory = SQL_Editor("SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [ID]='" & ARR(i) & "';")
        .LBHistory.Column = ArrHistory
    Next i

End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to fill six columns with the array you're getting from the data base. Both the `List` and `Count`properties replace the content of their lists when an array is assigned. The `AddItem` method allows you to append new items to the list, but in one dimension, only.

In order to append a new array of items, I believe you first need to read the current list into an array, append the new items to that array, then write the entirety back to the ListBox. Here's an example:

```
Dim arr()
Dim lb As ListBox
Dim numCols As Long
Dim rowCount As Long, colCount As Long
Dim numNewRecs As Long, newRecCount As Long

Set lb = Me.ListBox1
'You need to know how many new records are coming in
'Substitute this determination here:
numNewRecs = 2
numCols = lb.ColumnCount - 1

'Dimension the array for the current list plus the new records
ReDim arr(lb.ListCount - 1 + numNewRecs, numCols)
'Get the current list
For rowCount = 0 To lb.ListCount - 1
    For colCount = 0 To numCols
        arr(rowCount, colCount) = lb.List(rowCount, colCount)
    Next
Next
'Append the new records
For newRecCount = rowCount To rowCount + numNewRecs - 1
    For colCount = 0 To numCols
        arr(newRecCount, colCount) = "New data" & CStr(newRecCount)
    Next
Next
'Populate the ListBox
lb.List = arr()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Option Explicit


    Dim Form As HistoryFRM, ARR() As Variant, ArrHistory() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ....
    Set Form = New HistoryFRM
    With Form
        .Show vbModeless
        With .LBHistory
            .ColumnCount = 6
            For i = 0 To UBound(ARR)
                ArrHistory = SQL_Editor("SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [ID]='" & ARR(i) & "';")
                For j = LBound(ArrHistory) To UBound(ArrHistory)
                    .AddItem ArrHistory(j)
                Next
            Next
        End With
    End With
```